# XML in PHP (RSS reader)

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have this code and it works great

```
$i = 0; // counter
$url = "http://www.banki.ru/xml/news.rss"; // example url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser
print '<h2><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="'.$rss->channel->image->url.'" /> '.$rss->channel->title.'</h2>'; // channel title + img with src

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
if ($i < 1) { // parse only 1 item
print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';
}

$i++;
}
```

But I would like to show only second item from this feed. How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
if ($i < 1) { // parse only 1 item
print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';
}
```

to

```
if ($i == 1) { // parse only 1 item
print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works as brilliant.

Comment: @mrfox, if this is the solution to your problem, please consider to upvote and mark this answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$i = 0; // counter
$url = "http://www.banki.ru/xml/news.rss"; // example url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser
print '<h2><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="'.$rss->channel->image->url.'" /> '.$rss->channel->title.'</h2>'; // channel title + img with src

print '<a href="'.$rss->channel->item[1]->link.'">'.$rss->channel->item[1]->title.'</a><br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the if condition it will get you the second session

```html
<?php 

$i = 0; // counter
$url = "http://www.banki.ru/xml/news.rss"; // example url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser
print '<h2><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="'.$rss->channel->image->url.'" /> '.$rss->channel->title.'</h2>'; // channel title + img with src

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
if ($i > 1) { // parse only 1 item
print '<a href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->title.'</a><br />';
}

$i++;
}
```